# How can I iterate through the full web table with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

i want to scrape a web table with selenium and beautifulsoup. The table contains 10 x 'resultMainRow' and 4 x 'resultMainCell'.
Inside the 4th resultMainCell, there have 8 span classes,  for each holding an img src.
The following html code represents one of the table rows. I could only print out the relevant source code of the table. How can I iterate through the full web table together with the img src?

```html
<div class="resultMainTable">
   <div class="resultMainRow">
      <div class="resultMainCell_1 tableResult2">
           <a href="javascript:genResultDetails(2);" 
           title="Best of the date">20/006 </a></div>
      <div class="resultMainCell_2 tableResult2">21/01/2020</div>
      <div class="resultMainCell_3 tableResult2"></div>
      <div class="resultMainCell_4 tableResult2">
          <span class="resultMainCellInner"> 
              <img height="25" src="/info/images/icon/no_3abc”> </span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner"> 
              <img height="25" src = "/info/images/icon/no_14 " ></span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner"> 
               <img height="25" src "/info/images/icon/no_21 " ></span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner">
               <img height="25" src="/info/images/icon/no_28 " ></span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner">
               <img height="25" src=" /info/images/icon/no_37 "></span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner">   
               <img height="25" src="/info/images/icon/no_44 "></span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner">             
               <img height="6" src="/info/images/icon_happy " ></span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner" 
               <img height="25" src="/info/images/icon/smile "></span>
    </div>
       </div>
```

The table contains 10 x 'resultMainRow' and 4 x 'resultMainCell'.
Inside the 4th resultMainCell, there have 8 span classes,  for each holding an img src.

My code is as following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
         sixsix = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "resultMainTable"})
         print (sixsix)

        for row in sixsix:
            images = soup.findAll('img')
            for image in images:
                if len(images) == 8:
                aaa = images[1].find('src')
                bbb = images[2].find('src')
                ccc = images[3].find('src')
                ddd = images[4].find('src')
                eee = images[5].find('src')
                fff = images[6].find('src')
                ggg = images[7].find('src')
                hhh = images[8].find('src')
                print ((row.text), (image('src')))
```

Comment: Are there other `img` tags that you do not want? Are all the images you want contained in `<span class resultMainCellInner_1>` tags?

Comment: For images, I want the first 6 out of the 8.

Comment: yes, all the images are contained in <span class resultMainCellInner>. Thus there have 8 span classes in <div> 'resultMainCellInner', which is under <div resultMainCell_4>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this script to iterate over all rows of the table and extract text from first three cells and 8 URLs from src attributes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div class="resultMainTable">
    <div class="resultMainRow">
       <div class="resultMainCell">text1</div>
       <div class="resultMainCell">text2</div>
       <div class="resultMainCell">text3</div>
       <div class="resultMainCell">
            <div>
                 <div>
                      <span>
                           <img src="1" />
                           <img src="2" />
                           <img src="3" />
                           <img src="4" />
                           <img src="5" />
                           <img src="6" />
                           <img src="7" />
                           <img src="8" />
                      </span>
                 </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="resultMainRow">
       <div class="resultMainCell">text3</div>
       <div class="resultMainCell">text4</div>
       <div class="resultMainCell">text5</div>
       <div class="resultMainCell">
            <div>
                 <div>
                      <span>
                           <img src="9" />
                           <img src="10" />
                           <img src="11" />
                           <img src="12" />
                           <img src="13" />
                           <img src="14" />
                           <img src="15" />
                           <img src="16" />
                      </span>
                 </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>'''   

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.select('div.resultMainTable .resultMainRow'):
    v1, v2, v3, v4 = row.select('div.resultMainCell')
    imgs = [img['src'] for img in v4.select('img')]
    print(v1.text, v2.text, v3.text, *imgs)
```

Prints:

```
text1 text2 text3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
text3 text4 text5 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

---

EDIT (With real HTML code from edited question):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<div class="resultMainTable">
   <div class="resultMainRow">
      <div class="resultMainCell_1 tableResult2">
           <a href="javascript:genResultDetails(2);" 
           title="Best of the date">20/006 </a></div>
      <div class="resultMainCell_2 tableResult2">21/01/2020</div>
      <div class="resultMainCell_3 tableResult2"></div>
      <div class="resultMainCell_4 tableResult2">
          <span class="resultMainCellInner"> 
              <img height="25" src="/info/images/icon/no_3abc"> </span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner"> 
              <img height="25" src = "/info/images/icon/no_14 " ></span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner"> 
               <img height="25" src "/info/images/icon/no_21 " ></span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner">
               <img height="25" src="/info/images/icon/no_28 " ></span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner">
               <img height="25" src=" /info/images/icon/no_37 "></span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner">   
               <img height="25" src="/info/images/icon/no_44 "></span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner">             
               <img height="6" src="/info/images/icon_happy " ></span>
          <span class="resultMainCellInner" 
               <img height="25" src="/info/images/icon/smile "></span>
    </div>
       </div>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.select('div.resultMainTable .resultMainRow'):
    v1, v2, v3, v4 = row.select('div[class^="resultMainCell"]')
    imgs = [img['src'] for img in v4.select('img')]
    print(v1.text, v2.text, v3.text, *imgs)
```

Prints:

```
20/006  21/01/2020  /info/images/icon/no_3abc /info/images/icon/no_14   /info/images/icon/no_28   /info/images/icon/no_37  /info/images/icon/no_44  /info/images/icon_happy
```

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d79b6791edd9> in <module>()
     14 
     15 for row in soup.select('div.resultMainTable .resultMainRow'):
---> 16     v1, v2, v3, v4 = row.select('div.resultMainCell1')
     17     imgs = [img['src'] for img in v4.select('img')]
     18     print(row.text, *imgs)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)

Comment: I guess there might contain 1 value in each resultMainCell.

Comment: text1 text2 text3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
text3 text4 text5 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 This result format is exactly what i m expecting to have it.

Comment: @Gold1616 Without real HTML markup is hard to guess the correct code. Can you edit your question and put there real HTML code you're working with?

Comment: I have just  put the real html code for your refence. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2d86c77807be> in <module>()
     11 
     12 
---> 13 soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
     14 
     15 for row in soup.select('div.resultMainTable .resultMainRow'):

NameError: name 'txt' is not defined

Comment: @Gold1616 `txt` is variable, where HTML string is stored. Replace it with your variable which contains HTML code.

Comment: What does * placed before the variable img means?

Comment: @Gold1616 `*` is unpacking list `imgs` into arguments for `print()` function. More here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/

Comment: row.select('div[class^="resultMainCell"]'). Why it is put ^ a bitwise operator here?

Comment: @Gold1616 Here, the '^' it isn't bitwise operator, but CSS selector. It select every DIV with class that begins with resultMainCell. More about CSS selectors here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: I cant create a pandas dataframe with * imgs. The code is as follow:

Comment: result_item = {
        'xxx'         : v1.text[:6],
        'yyy'         : v2.text,
        'zzz'         : *imgs
   }
    
    result.append(result_item)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(result)

print(df)

Comment: File "<ipython-input-1-9009f1300cca>", line 24
    'zzz'         : *imgs
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I cant create a pandas dataframe with * imgs. how can i convert the unpacked img list into pandas?

Comment: @Gold1616 To not clutter the comment section here, I recommend to open a new question here on StackOverflow (where I and/or others can help you).